Unable to access server running in k8s pod from WSL host with docker-desktop installation
I'm running docker-desktop with WSL2.0 ubuntu on windows. I created a k8s deployment in the wsl ubuntu host. The deployment has one pod where I'm running a simple server program(runs forever, accepts udp connections, prints received buffer from client("Hi Server"), returns "Hi Client"). Server is  running on port 5000. netstat inside the container gives me this -
# netstat -au
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*                          

I've written a service to expose the port outside the cluster by using nodePort. The deploy and service yaml looks like this -
apiVersion: apps/v1                                                                                                  kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myserver-deployment
  labels:
    app: myserver                                                                                                    spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myservercontainer
        image: myserverimage:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          protocol: UDP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myserver-service                                                                                             spec:
  selector:
    app: myserver
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 32001

The output -
$ kubectl get service
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          28d
myserver-service   LoadBalancer   10.96.214.107   localhost     5000:32001/UDP   114m

Now I tried to run a udp client program(connects to server, sends "Hi server", receives "Hi client" and dies) in ubuntu host machine(172.21.109.211) and tried to execute.The WSL ubuntu host machine is where the k8s cluster is also running. As per my understanding, from windows the server should be accessible at localhost:32001 and from WSL host it should be <host_ip>:32001. So my client program tried to reach server running in pod at 172.21.109.211:32001.
The Client hangs on receivefrom() when i give an unreachable/nonexistant ip. But when i'm using 172.21.109.211(host ip) for server, client is getting nothing in receivefrom() and then exiting without any print(nothing in buffer). Neither server nor client prints anything. Server listening as it is, client exits after execution(no crash).
Part of client code for reference -
{
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.21.109.211");
servaddr.sin_port = htons(32001);
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
// create datagram socket
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
// connect to server
if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
{
printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
exit(0);
}
printf("Connection successful\n");
sendto(sockfd, message, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
// waiting for response
recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, NULL);
puts(buffer);
// close the descriptor
close(sockfd);
}

I'm confused about what is happenning. Is 172.21.109.211:32001 right address to reach the pod server?
P.S. the same program runs successfully(prints) when both server and client runs on the host,
or
when server runs in a container created by docker-compose with "-p 172.21.109.211:32001:5000" and client runs on the host

Refer to this Stack Link which might be helpful to resolve your issue.

Pranay thanks for the link. But my issue is I can't connect server running on k8s pod from wsl2. But when i run the same server from a container using docker-compose the connection works seamlessly.

Refer to this document which might be helpful for you
